# iphone: detecting and replacing a URL in an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, url, nsstring

I currently have an NSString which can take in a message body similar to a tweet.

E.g.

NSString *sampleText = "This text contains the link http://www.google.com"

I need to write a function that can take in this text, detect that a url exists in the string, and be able to replace the url with a placeholder text.

E.g. after the function is used, the text should equal:

sampleText = "This contains contains a LINK"

Can someone please tell me how I can do this? Do I need to use RegEx?

Comment: I would love to tell you more if you actually cared to award best answers.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use regular expressions. I think first you need to make up your mind about which cases you want to cover, what about www.google.com for example? That should help you decide how to do it. The easiest case, just looking for http:// and replacing the string until the next whitespace does not need any regex magic..

Answer (score 2):

iOS 4 has `[NSRegularExpression replaceMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:]` which looks like a good bet. (It expects an `NSMutableString`.)